# React web app does not work and keeps refreshing on mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, mobile, mobile-safari, loading, mobile-chrome

This web App(reactjs) works fine on desktop and tablets.

However, when trying it on mobile browser(like Safari), the progress bar keeps flickering and refreshing like:

[Please click to view the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cnoc.gif)

I have tried on Safari and Chrome(e.g. iOS12-14 & Android 10-12), all display the same result.

Anyone know why this happened?

Or why the progress bar keeps flickering and refreshing on mobile browsers, but works well on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an infinity refresh did you checked useEffect / useMemo / Function Call. The only thing that i can do now, is telling you where you can possibly check in your code, but for a better understanding of your problem, should provide more info about your code or more techical information

Comment: I have found the problem is not from the react app, but thanks for reminding me of this.